# How do move forward and back through an array / object of images?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I'm importing an object that holds *urls* to images. The function below loads a random image from the `array` and never repeats and works great. However I want a function that displays the last image seen.

To clarify I'm displaying one image at a time. I have a function below that loads the next image in an `array`. I want to have a function to load the last seen image. Allowing to user to scan forward and back through the `array`.

Updated version: Doesn't retrieve the previous image.

```
window.shownCache = [];

function receivedData(data) {
      function nextPicture() {
            if (window.currentlyShownOffer) {
                var tagArray = data[window.currentlyShownOffer.Tag];
                tagArray.splice(tagArray.indexOf(currentlyShownOffer), 1);
                //alert(window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesId);
                }


         var tags = Object.keys(data);
         var randomTag = tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)];
         var tagArray = data[randomTag];


   window.currentlyShownOffer = tagArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tagArray.length)];
   window.shownCache.push(window.currentlyShownOffer);
   document.getElementById('top5').src = window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesPath;
   alert(window.shownCache);
   };

   nextPicture();

   function lastPicture() {
        document.getElementById('top5').src = window.shownCache[window.shownCache.length - 1].ImagesPath;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have something like:

```
window.shownCache = [];
function changeOfferPicture() {
  …
  window.currentlyShownOffer = tagArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tagArray.length)];
  window.shownCache.push(window.currentlyShownOffer);
  document.getElementById('top5').src = window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesPath;
  }
```

And now, your last shown offer will always be at `widow.shownCache[window.shownCache.length - 1]`, and the elements before it will be your entire history of shown offers.

Comment: I'm currently getting broken images when looking for the last image. I adding the function to the above question.

Comment: @moss it should be `document.getElementById('top5').src = window.shownCache[window.shownCache.length - 1].ImagesPath;`

Comment: I updated above. The lastPicture function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://jimdo.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg" id="box" width="300" height="200">
<input type="button" value="show image" id="showImge" />
<input type="button" value="prev" id="prev" />
<input type="button" value="next" id="next" />
```

**JQuery**

```
var items = [{
    ImagesPath: 'http://jimdo.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg'
}, {
    ImagesPath: 'http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/rawfile/2013/11/offset_RonnyRitschel_23712-1-660x660.jpg'
}, {
    ImagesPath: 'http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01654/THRHLAP10THINGSTOS_1654673g.jpg'
}, {
    ImagesPath: 'http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01654/THRHLAP10THINGSTOS_1654676g.jpg'
}];
var rndIndexCount = 0;
var cache = [{
    RndIndex: rndIndexCount,
    ImageIndex: 0
}];
var currentCache;

function changeOfferPicture() {
    rndIndexCount++
    var imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    var currentItem = items[imageIndex];
    currentCache = {
        RndIndex: rndIndexCount,
        ImageIndex: imageIndex
    };
    cache.push(currentCache);
    document.getElementById('box').src = currentItem.ImagesPath;
}
$("#prev,#next").click(function () {
    var isNext = $(this).attr("id") == "next";
    if (currentCache) {
        var result = cache.filter(function (obj) {
            var findIndex = isNext ? currentCache.RndIndex + 1 : currentCache.RndIndex - 1;
            console.log(findIndex);
            return obj.RndIndex == findIndex;
        })[0];
        if (result) {
            console.log(result.RndIndex + " , " + result.ImageIndex);
            currentCache = result;
            document.getElementById('box').src = items[currentCache.ImageIndex].ImagesPath;
        }
    }
});
$("#showImge").click(function () {
    changeOfferPicture();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/9nkygLvg/4/)

Comment: Any change you can be more specific with the prev image function. I'm not sure how to write it. Especially what you mean by obj.find

Comment: This demo doesn't work very well, the next button doesn't work and the previous button only works once.

Comment: I have not had time to write it completely.
With a few changes you can implement it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are doing too much and you lose flexibility because of this, making changes more complicated to implement.

Just split your functionality between multiple single-task functions. In the sample below, I assume that `changeOfferImage` actually changes the `src` of the image and that `nextRandomOfferImage` returns the next random image. You will call `showNextOfferImage` to go forward and `showPreviousOfferImage` to go backward.

```
var displayedOfferImages = [], imageIndex = -1;

function showNextOfferImage() {

    var lookingInDisplayedImages = imageIndex < (displayedOfferImages.length - 1),
        offerImage;

    if (lookingInDisplayedImages) {
        offerImage = nextDisplayedImage();
    } else {
        offerImage = nextRandomOfferImage();
        imageIndex = displayedOfferImages.push(offerImage) - 1;
    }

    changeOfferPicture(offerImage);

}

function showPreviousOfferImage() {
    var previousImage = previousDisplayedImage();

    if (previousImage) changeOfferPicture(offerImage);
}

function previousDisplayedImage() {
    return displayedOfferImages[--imageIndex];
}

function nextDisplayedImage() {
    return displayedOfferImages[++imageIndex];
}
```